# Is there a possibility to execute a range function over an aggregation in PromQL?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

Usually, having a range function and an aggregation in PromQL is constructed like this:

`sum by(label) (increase(metric{label="label"}[1h]))`

with `sum` being the aggregator and `increase` being the range function.

However, the metric that I'm trying to query **only** returns `1` at different times with different label values. It's basically an ever-increasing counter. The (stacked) graph in Grafana without any functions applied to it looks like this:
[image: graph]
So, applying a range function on this metric is useless, because it never changes (remains 1). I would like to `sum by(label)` first, and **then** execute `increase` over the result. It would look like something along the lines of this:

`increase((sum by(label) (metric{label=~".*"}))[1h])`

I tried doing this, naturally, looking at the documentation and experimenting with the syntax, to no avail. I even tried to use two seperate queries, which also wasn't very successful. I also tried the new query 'Builder' in Grafana 9 to see if that's possible, without success...

So, does anybody have a suggestion on how to apply a range function to an aggregation by(label)? Unfortunately, I can't directly change the data in Prometheus, and have to rely on the result of the query.

Comment: You said it always returns “1” but at the same time it’s “ever increasing counter” — what do you mean?

Comment: @star67 as can be seen in the graph, the query returns metrics with different label values that all carry the value '1'. The amount of these metrics returned by the query increases continuously.

Comment: if each label has value '1' and you have lots of such metrics, why do you need `sum by(label)`? "sum by label" means that label value is preserved in the result instant vector...

Comment: @star67 `sum by(label)` basically 'sorts' all of these metrics in groups. The graph as shown in the image looks the same, but instead of many metrics with the value '1', it displays the sum of metrics equal to the number of values for a certain label. In my case, the graph above shows only 3 different colors after summing by label. But I need to get the `increase` of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Prometheus Subqueries

> It would look like something along the lines of this:
> increase((sum by(label) (metric{label=~".*"}))[1h])

The problem with this query is that you try to pass an **instant** vector to a function that accepts a **range** vector (see [increase](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase) and [range vs. instant vectors](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-vectors)).

To get a range vector you need to make several queries, which is possible with either recording rules or [subqueries](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/):

`increase((sum by(label) (metric{label=~".*"}))[1h:])`

#### Count Aggregation

It's simple, the `sum` aggregation is used, but since you don't care about the value (always `1`), consider using `count` (see [aggregation-operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators)).

#### Wrong Data Model

Obviously, there is a problem with your data, that won't let you properly apply the counter functions (such as `increase`).

You have:

```
12:00
{label="blue"} 1

12:30
{label="blue"} 1
{label="red"} 1

13:00
{label="blue"} 1
{label="red"} 1
{label="green"} 1
```

While it should be:

```
12:00
{label="blue"} 1

12:30
{label="blue"} 2
{label="red"} 1

13:00
{label="blue"} 3
{label="red"} 2
{label="green"} 1
```

The current approach has many drawbacks, only a few of them:

- waste of memory resources (N metrics with a value instead of a metric with value N)
- waste of computation resources (additional query to "get a counter")
- the result is not resistant to node restarts, since aggregation is applied **before** the counter function (`increase`) (see ["rate then sum"](https://rate%20and%20then%20sum))